# I have a King of Enchancia, but not 2

Tags: riddle, wordplay, movies

> 1- Created by a man born in a Dutch Broken Land
>
> 2- Eosinophil Granule Ontogeny Transcript
>
> 3- Tittle
>
> 4- Golden flecks powered by bacteria
>
> 5 Kentucky Fried Chicken

What movie am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it

> Space balls?

1- Created by a man born in a Dutch Broken Land

> Created in brooklyn - Mel Brooks

2- Eosinophil Granule Ontogeny Transcript

> EGOT - Mel is an EGOT winner

3- Tittle

> There's a character called Dot (Matrix)

4- Golden flecks powered by bacteria

> Yogurt maybe? (golden and yogurt is pretty much bacteria)

5 Kentucky Fried Chicken

> Has a character named Col. Sandurz (sp?)

Comment: Nice job :) One of my favorite movies of all times

Comment: edited to add in potential answers for tittle and golden flecks, the title is still confusing me though

Comment: The title is related to a character in the film as well.